# 'Form submit.co' sending emails, but no data is received

Tags: html, forms, form-submit, portfolio

I am using https://formsubmit.co/ in my form, for retrieving emails sent on my portfolio website. An email gets sent to my account, however non of the information in the form appears in this email.

I've watched some tutorials of how to implement this and my code is seemingly identical. Would appreciate some tips on what may be going on here
my code:

```html
<form action="https://formsubmit.co/robin.jessica.little.95@gmail.com" method="POST">
          <ul>
          <li><input type ="Text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name"  required></li>
          <li><input type ="Text" id="subject" placeholder="Subject"  required></li>
          <li><input type ="Email" id ="email" placeholder="Your Email"  required></li>
          <li><input type ="Text" id ="phone" placeholder="Your Phone Number" required></li>
          <textarea id = "message " rows="10" autocomplete="off" placeholder="How can I help you?"></textarea><button id = "sumbitMessage">Send</button>
        </ul>
        </form>
```

Followed some other tutorials with different methods, but have not got anything to work so far, so alternatively if you could share some better resources I would appreciate that too.

Comment: Typo: You skipped over step 2 of [the instructions](https://formsubmit.co/)

Comment: [The  placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: Try my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to get information each input must have a "name" attribute. Like below:

```
<form action="https://formsubmit.co/your@email.com" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="name" required>
     <input type="email" name="email" required>
     <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Also, take the inputs out of the unordered list.

Answer (score -1):

Try this out - I've tried it and it works : See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7u2rwxgp/1/)

```
  <form action="https://formsubmit.co/robin.jessica.little.95@gmail.com" method="POST">
              <ul> 
              <li> Your Name <input type ="Text" id="name" name="name"   required></li>
              <li>Subject <input type ="Text" id="subject" name="subject"   required></li>
              <li>Email <input type ="email" id ="email" name="email"    required></li>
              <li>Your Phone Number<input type ="Text" id ="phone" name="phone" required></li>How can I help you? <br>
              <textarea id = "message " rows="10" autocomplete="off" ></textarea>

            </ul>
    <button type="submit" id = "sumbitMessage">Send</button>

            </form>
```